# jquery not fast enough to change top left value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've a very simple logic here. I create container, and put it ontop of the required location where I need effect to happen css font zoom in this case.

But problem is if you move mouse fast enough around the .sortable li, words start to fly around!

Demonstration: http://mac.idev.ge:800/words/ hover on the words.

Weird isn't it? How can I optimise my code to fix this problem?

```
// Zoom on hover effect for sortable items
// Create empty container
$("body").append("<div id='words_zoom'></div>");
var wz = $("#words_zoom");

$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var item = $(this);
        var item_offset = item.offset();

        // position the zoom container
        var central_left = item_offset.left;
        var central_top = item_offset.top;

        wz.show();

        wz.css({"left":central_left,"top":central_top});

        wz.html(item.html());

        //
        //wz.stop().animate({"font-size":"2.2em",top:"-=3",left:"-=3"}, 300, "easeOutExpo");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        //
    }
}, ".sortable li:not('.delete-text')");

//
$(document).on("mouseleave", "#words_zoom", function() {
    //wz.css({"font-size":"2em",top:"+=3",left:"+=3"}).hide();
    wz.hide();
    wz.css({"left":0,"top":0});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually in your CSS:

```
#words_zoom {
    background: #fff;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

Try changing the transition property to only transition on attributes you want it to (I'm guessing you want font-size alone).

```
#words_zoom {
    background: #fff;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    -webkit-transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
    transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
}
```